# Simple snap scrolling implementation

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollview, anchor

Good day lads. Can anyone direct me on the general approach towards achieving snap scrolling like these on the following sites - http://fantasy.co/ and https://www.ramotion.com/.

Generally what I want to know is how to listen for the scroll event and scroll to an anchor or an element on the page such as can be seen from those sites. I've tried searching online but all the tutorials seem to be doing this on click of an anchor link whereas I want to achieve this on scroll. Anyone able to help?

Comment: You might be able to use something like fullPage.js to achieve an effect like that: https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Comment: @Derek Hopper Thanks. Funny thing is I literally just found that after posting this question. Scroll hijacking seems to be seriously frowned upon. Why do you think that is?

Comment: There are likely a ton of different opinions out there, so don't take my opinion as gospel or anything. Scrolljacking, like many other effects or designs people put out there, is tricky. There's a fine line between using the effect the right way and completely confusing your users. In general, the normal user doesn't really care about what effects you put on your website. They just want to read an article or get something done, right?

Comment: Yeah. I see your point. I'm just using it for learning purposes anyway. Will see how it goes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you have tagged your question with jquery and have asked about general directions, I'd say explore

```
jquery(window).scroll(function(){
    // handle scrolling here
});
```

Other things to note are:

- you may need methods to get current scrolling position (see `window.scrollY` and `document.documentElement.scrollTop`)
- to find out scrolling direction, you can create a `prevScrollPosition` variable and compare it with current position on scroll (and update it in the end of your scroll handler)
- learn about `.offsetParent`, `.offsetHeight` and `.offsetTop` properties of elements to calculate desirable positions to scroll to
- learn also `window.scrollTo` method to be able to manipulate scrolling

Tricky thing is to make you scrolling smooth (if you implement your snapping as instant scrolling to certain position, it will be rather confusing, so you have to think of acceleration and deceleration).